# Какие блокировки нужны в данных сценариях

Tags: mysql, sql

Я запутался, с уровнями блокировок, изоляциями.
У меня стоит MySQL 5.7, движок InnoDB.

Вот несколько сценариев:

1) С таблицы могут считывать(select) несколько потоков одновременно, одни и те же строки

2) С таблицы могут считывать(select) несколько потоков одновременно, разные строки

3) С таблицы могут считывать(select), производить определенные расчеты, а потом перезаписывать(update), несколько потоков одновременно, но каждый поток индивидуальную строку

4) С таблицы могут считывать(select), производить определенные расчеты, а потом перезаписывать(update),  несколько потоков одновременно, одну и туже строку

5) С таблицы могут считывать(select), производить определенные расчеты, а потом перезаписывать(update),  несколько потоков одновременно, всю таблицу

6) С таблицы могут считывать(select) диапазон, добавлять(insert) строку, несколько потоков одновременно

Какие блокировки мне расставить? Все запросы я делаю отдельно, то есть, прочел, потом расчеты(расчеты почти не занимают времени 0.001-0.002 сек), потом другим запросом обновил

Comment: с простыми чтениями проблем нет никаких. для начала задайте себе вопрос, что должны видеть или не должны видеть читающие если в это время вы собираетесь менять строку. обычно то что читающие видят предыдущее состояние, а потом видят уже новое состояние никаких проблем не вызывает. проблемы могут быть только если кто то прочитал строку, а потом, основываясь на тех данных ее обновляет. Вот для этих редких случаев есть `select for update`. А вообще на ваш вопрос ответить невозможно. Явные блокировки нужны крайне редко и решение можно принять только в каждом конкретном случае

Comment: есть баланс, игрок в процессе игры его меняет(читает/считает/пишет), тут оператор решил снять кредиты: читаю баланс в свою переменную, проверяю чтобы баланс был больше суммы снятия, уменьшаю баланс, сохраняю в таблицу, как сделать чтоб игрок не вмешался в процесс и оператор дождался пока игрок закончит свой?

Comment: А изменения баланса конкретного игрока частые ?

Comment: И почему расчет идет не в том же запросе, а как то отдельно

Comment: игрок менять может каждую секунду, две, оператор раз в 10 минут может раз в час

Comment: расчеты игрока это объемный код я его не осилю на sql, да и не думаю что идея хорошая

Comment: вы дайте какой нибудь пример, я попробую на практике, если будут конфликты

Comment: и ваши расчеты на клиенте считают именно исходя из последнего значения в БД, они не могут посчитать дельту и потом ее применить

Comment: я не понял о чем вы

Comment: алгоритм на клиете не может посчитать, что счет должен изменится скажем на -10, не основываясь при этом на текущем состоянии баланса. А потом выполнить `update tab set balance=balance-10 where ... and balance-10>0`, например

Comment: В общем если не может, то всегда перед изменением читать значение с помощью `select for update` должно быть более чем достаточно. другие, кто то же читает для изменения будут ожидать данных пока запись не пройдет

Comment: в принципе возможно переписывать конечно придется). ок, а как будет выглядеть запрос sql где мы сначала читаем, потом в том же запросе выполняем 1 проверку типа больше меньше, а потом сохраняем и чтоб в это все никто не влез?

Comment: так вот тот `update` что я привел двумя коментами выше

Comment: можете весь запрос select  потом if  и update?

Comment: Это и есть один запрос. вместо `if` условие прямо в `where balance-10>=0`. select не нужен, потому что update сам получит текущее значение и изменит его когда написано `balance=balance-10` если результирующий баланс при таком условии в where окажется меньше нуля, то запрос не найдет подходящих строк и ничего не поменяет. проверив количество обновленных строк вы увидите 0 и помете что не хватило средств (т.к. ошибок при этом нет)

Comment: @Mike "В общем если не может, то всегда перед изменением читать значение с помощью select for update" Если я так прочту из одной ячейки таблицы, которую каждый клиент и читает и пишет, потом у себя в программе сделаю определенные расчеты, пока я буду делать эти расчеты, никто не сможет прочитать от туда? Если так, то как потом отменить запрет? Обычным update?

Comment: Если не сложно покажите пример, в котором, действия(select, мои расчеты, update) происходят с одной и той же ячейкой таблицы, и пока первый клиент не закончит второй должен ждать

Comment: И еще такой вопрос, если ни какие блокировки не ставить, то второй клиент просто прочтет не обновленные данные?

Comment: Поэксперименитровали бы, что самый лучший способ проверить свои догадки и быть уверенным, что потом в приложении не возникнет проблем. В документации написано что чтение `for update` блокирует запись точно так же как и сама операция update. Работает это в пределах транзакции ...

Comment: Вот я сейчас проверил и мне не понравилось ... Во первых обязательно надо начать транзакцию begin. Блокировка тогда живет до тех пор пока вы не дадите commit или rollback. (не забудьте отключить на соединении автокоммит после каждой операции). Открыл два окна с MySQL. в одном даю begin и select for update. в другом: просто select работает. select for update зависает и ждет пока в первом окне завершат транзакцию. А не понравилось то, что чтение for update другой записи в таблице так же зависает, потому что индекс заблочен и что то мне подсказыаает, что в MySQL это не лечится

Comment: И этот эксперимент у меня занял 3 минуты... По моему это гораздо быстрее, чем пытаться выудить что то конкретное из книг, гугла и SO. Да, пробовал на InnoDB, с MyISAM говорят все грустно

Comment: @Mike Спасибо! Буду блокировать у себя в программе(запрещать другому пользователю совершать транзакции), где я немного ориентируюсь, А через что вы эксперименитруете,  в какой программе?

Comment: В консоли запускаю mysql

Comment: Как то мне не нравится эта затея с блокировками. у меня ощущение, что все клиенты только и будут что делать, висеть в ожидании пока им дадут обновить БД. Если MySql блоичил одну запись, было бы отлично. Но этот глобальный блок которого будут ждать все клиенты imho перебор. То же и блоков в программе касается, как то слишком жестко останавливать все операции пока кто то один обновляет одну запись

Comment: запрет поставлю когда оператор с клиентом одну запись меняют, а когда запись все клиенты меняют не буду блокировать, могут потеряться некоторые суммы но это на данный момент менее критично чем сервер упадет, а там найду способ, либо позже переписывать буду, поменяю алгоритм на тот что вы предложили, что б в update менять, а потом проверять если строка поменялась мнять значение у себя